# maximum separation distance between 2 paths

Tags: geography

I have 2 geography paths, each consists of multiple points (Latitude and Longitude).
Both path start and end at the same coordinate.
How can I find maximum separation distance between 2 paths?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the maximum value of path distance given using Pythagoras' theorem, and using `sqrt(pow((lat2 - lat1), 2) + pow((long2 - long1), 2))`. You may or may not use the Haversine formula if more precision is required (Earth is a sphere, for long paths using a formula suited for planar geometry will give pretty big errors)

Haversine can be implemented in C this way:

```
float R = 6371.0; //Radius of the earth in km
float dlat = lat2 - lat1; //latitudes in radians
float dlong = long2 - long1;
float a = sin(dlat/2)*sin(dlat/2) + cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*sin(dlong/2)*sin(dlong/2);
float c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) );
float d = R * c; //distance in km
```

To convert decimal degrees to radians:

```
float toRad(float degrees_coord) { 
  return degrees_coord * MATH_PI / 180.0;
}
```

MATH_PI, sqrt() and pow() are all in the library math.h
Remember to `#include <math.h>`

If the two paths do not have the same length, the sampling would be have to be remapped: say path #1 has 100 steps and path #2 has 150 steps i.e. the position of step 20 of path #1 and step 30 of path #2 will be used to calculate the distance.

Iterating this process through all steps and looking for the highest value can be a valid method.